# Why can't GHC work out which field to use in this case statement?

Tags: haskell

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}

resolveProjectConfig :: IO (Maybe ProjectConfig)

config :: IO ()
config = do
  config <- resolveProjectConfig
  case config of
    Just c -> putStrLn (name c)
    Nothing -> putStrLn "broken"
```

GHC seems to know in `Just c` that c is a `ProjectConfig`, but in `putStrLn (name c)` I get the error "Ambiguous occurence name. It could refer to either the field name... [list of other stuff with a name field]".

Surely if it knows what `c` is, it should be able to pick the correct name function? Is there some way to have it figure it out, without adding `c :: ProjectConfig` ?

Comment: This is documented behaviour: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/records/overloaded-record-fields/duplicate-record-fields

Comment: It might be better to just use `Just (ProjectConfig {name=n}) -> putStrLn n`

Comment: This is a current limitation of GHC: we need the explicit annotation. I have no idea about what would prevent to use the inferred type. Surely this is quite annoying for OOP programmers, who are used to be able to write `c.name` without having to specify which type `c` has.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem great tip! It doesn't look quite as nice as I'd like it to. But it works.

Comment: I wish that `DuplicateRecordFields` would never have been a thing, I've always seen this (like the earlier `RecordFieldPuns`) as just a half-baked, ad-hoc attempt at removing a restriction in standard Haskell _against the grain_ of the language. Fortunately, we now have `OverloadedRecordFields` which does it (kind-of) properly; hopefully all libraries relying on `DuplicateRecordFields` will soon switch to that.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Is `OverloadedRecordFields` the name of an actual extension? I don't have it in my GHC. Googling around it seems to refer to a group of individual (partially?) implemented extensions. Are you referring to those?

Comment: @chi the relevant extension is `-XOverloadedLabels`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a current limitation of GHC. We need to write `name (c :: ProjectConfig)` to disambiguate. Not very convenient.

As an alternative, you can patter match on a more informative pattern (as suggested by Willem Van Onsem):

```
case config of
   Just (ProjectConfig {name=n}) -> putStrLn n
```

This will disambiguate since `name` is used only in the pattern after `ProjectConfig`, so it is accepted.

Another, more cumbersome, alternative would be to use a custom typeclass. Assuming  all `name` fields are strings, we can use:

```
class HasName a where
    getName :: a -> String

instance HasName ProjectConfig where
    getName = name

instance HasName Other where -- for other types having the same field
    getName = name

config :: IO ()
config = do
  config <- resolveProjectConfig
  case config of
    Just c -> putStrLn (getName c)
    ...
```

(Why this is not done automatically under the hood is beyond me.)